# Java Recon Job - Fastest and generic solution

Tags: java, oracle, mongodb, bigdata

Currently, I am running my application in RDS and in the process of moving to MongoDB. For now, we have a synch job which syncs data from Oracle to Mongo as and when row gets added/modified or deleted.
 Write is happening only on Oracle.

Planning to come up with a recon job which compares the source and the target data.  I am trying for full recon which fetches all the data from oracle and then get then compares with MongoDB to find the descrepencies.

I am planning for the below approach.

Note, The oracle DB size could be in TeraBytes.

1) Get first thousand rows from oracle table A. ( Simple JDBC results approach )

2) For each entry, create a map of key values. ( Map)

3) Get the corresponding data from MongoDB and convert the data based on oracle format.

4) For each entry, create a map of key values.

5) Compare these two map to find if they are same. ( Oracle Map equals Mongoldb Map )

6) Repeat the same for next rows ....

But, this approach is taking much time even i do using multi threading. I do not have much idea on Big Data, but open for new ideas.

Is there any other way or technology which can be used here for parallel processing.

Note, there could be some tables which are mapped straight forward b/w oracle and Mongo. Few tables are in denormalized form in Mongo.

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by 'recon'? Thanks.

Comment: I meant reconcile job.